# form_validation class does not load (codeigniter)

Tags: php, codeigniter, validation, autoloader

My script fails to load form_validation class.

I called it from autoload.php, controller's _*construct* method and the method i was intend to use (*ie. login() method*)

**autoload.php**

```
$autoload['libraries'] = array('database', 'Login', 'Template', 'form_validation', 'session');
```

**controller**

```
<?php
class Login extends CI_Controller
{
function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct();
    $this->load->model('user_model');
    $this->load->library('form_validation');
}

function logmein()
{       
    $this->load->library('form_validation');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('userEmail', 'email', 'trim|required|valid_email|callback__check_login');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('userPassword', 'password', 'trim|required');
```

*please do note that, i did not try to load the class from all the three places, i tried each one solely, and the combinations, but no success. I'm running **PHP Version 5.3.5** on my localhost with **XAMPP** on **windows 7**. My real server is linux so if it works well on linux, i can live with that =)*

**update:** i have var_dumped and checked the resources, and both _user_model_ and _form_validation_ seem to work well. however, when i `var_dump($this->user_model)` or `var_dump($this->form_validation)` returns `NULL`.

Comment: What do you mean by `fails`? What error are you getting?

Comment: it simply does not load at all.  _Message: Undefined property: Login::$form_validation_

Comment: what happens when you put die("validation found"); as the first line of the form_validation library?

Comment: **update:** i have var_dumped my code in `constructor` and `logmein` methods, they both seem to loaded the form_validation class.

Comment: Can you autoload ONLY the form_validation class? `$autoload['libraries'] = array('form_validation');`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All of my code was actually error-less.

However in one of my library classes, i have extended a controller class to load another library which was causing all of my errors.

I have removed it and used `$CI =& get_instance();` method for loading other classes and everything works fine now.

Answer (score 0):

You have two `Login` classes which are being loaded simultaneously. I'll bet money that they are causing a collision. Change the name of the Library class to LoginTools or something like that, and that will help.

Comment: that was the case, however i've noticed it and removed it from the library completely since i'm writing a new one, however still no success. i also have renamed my login controller to something else, in case any conflicts, but no success.    in addition, when i call the load method from the ___construct_ method, it does not throw an error which means it finds and loads it somewhere.