# PHP login using CodeIgniter

Tags: php, html, codeigniter, authentication

I'm trying a login on PHP using CodeIgniter.

My code is this:

Login view

```
<div class="section section_with_padding" id="usuarios"> 
        <h1>Acceso a Usuarios</h1> 
        <div class="half left">
            <h4>Usuario Existente</h4>
            <p>Si posee una cuenta en Garage, introduzca su nombre de usuario y contraseña para acceder.</p>
            <div id="login">
                 <!-- Usado para que muestre los errores de validacion -->
                
                <form method="post" name="users" action="index.php/verificarlogin">
                    <div class="left">
                        <label for="username">Nombre de Usuario:</label> 
                        <input name="username" type="text" class="required input_field" id="username" maxlength="30" required/>
                    </div>
                    <div class="right">                           
                        <label for="password">Contraseña:</label> 
                        <input name="password" type="password" class="validate-email required input_field" id="email" maxlength="30" required/>
                    </div>
                    <div class="clear"></div>
                    <input type="submit" class="submit_btn float_l" name="submit" id="submit" value="Entrar" />
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Don't mind the right div, that code is still not coded...

My verificarlogin (verify login) controller

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class VerificarLogin extends CI_Controller {

function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct();
    $this->load->model('usuarios','',TRUE);
}

function index()
{
    //Este metodo tendra las credenciales de validacion
    $this->load->library('Form_validation');

    $this->Form_validation->set_rules('username', 'Username', 'trim|required|xss_clean');
    $this->Form_validation->set_rules('password', 'Password', 'trim|required|xss_clean|callback_check_database');

    if($this->Form_validation->run() == FALSE)
    {
            //Si la validacion falla, el usuario es redireccionado a la pagina de login
            $this->load->view('#usuarios');
    }
    else
    {
            //Si la validacion pasa, el usuario es redireccionado a donde deberia ir
            redirect('home_usuarios', 'refresh');
    }

}

function check_database($password)
{
    //Si la validacion de campo es exitosa, valida contra la base de datos
    $username = $this->input->post('username');

    //Pregunta en la base de datos
    $result = $this->user->login($username, $password);

    if($result)
    {
        $sess_array = array();
        foreach($result as $row)
        {
            $sess_array = array(
            'id' => $row->id,
            'username' => $row->username
            );
            $this->session->set_userdata('logged_in', $sess_array);
        }
        return TRUE;
    }
    else
    {
        $this->form_validation->set_message('check_database', 'Nombre de Usuario o Contraseña invalida');
        return false;
    }
  }
}
```

When I run it it gives this error:

> A PHP Error was encountered
>
> Severity: Notice
>
> Message: Undefined property: VerificarLogin::$Form_validation
>
> Filename: controllers/verificarlogin.php
>
> Line Number: 32

The line the error is marking is this:

```
$this->Form_validation->set_rules('username', 'Username', 'trim|required|xss_clean');
```

I have reserch and I found that error is caused because the lacks this line

```
$this->load->library('Form_validation');
```

But this line is already in my code...

The libraries database and session are loaded by autoload.

I don't know whan I'm doing wrong... It's like the code can't access the libraries...

Comment: try in all lowercase : `$this->form_validation`

Comment: @egig I try that already...

Comment: did you load `form_validation` library?

Comment: @MajidGolshadi It's loaded in the line before the error...

Comment: all people are mentioning the same approach, maybe your installation is somehow broken?

Comment: see this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6708287/form-validation-class-does-not-load-codeigniter i think help you

Comment: @soupdiver I don't think so, a new installa of CodeIgniter gives me the same problem...

Comment: change action="index.php/verificarlogin" into 

action="<?php echo base_url ();?>verificarlogin"

Comment: @codeigniterleaner That give me a nice `Not Found: The requested URL Project/verificarlogin was not found on this server.`

Comment: @MajidGolshadi I'm sorry, I didn't understand the solution of that link... and I don't think it will serve me because I don't have a custom library.

Answer (score 0):

If you look up the [documentation](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter%20/user-guide/libraries/form_validation.html) you can see their example:

```
<?php

class Form extends CI_Controller {

  function index()
  {
    $this->load->helper(array('form', 'url'));

    $this->load->library('form_validation');

    if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE)
    {
      $this->load->view('myform');
    }
    else
    {
      $this->load->view('formsuccess');
    }
  }
}
?>
```

and they do `$this->form_validation` and not `$this->Form_validation` so try changing the name of the property which you wanna access.

Also try to fix the name when loading the library `$this->load->library('form_validation');`

Comment: have you tried looking up in your system folder if the `libraries/Form_validation.php` file does exist?

Comment: It does exist. I check the folder.

Answer (score 0):

function `check_database` doesn't load `Form validation`. Try to move this line
`$this->load->library('form_validation')` to controller constructor:

```
function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct();
    $this->load->model('usuarios','',TRUE);
    $this->load->library('form_validation');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume your working folder name is Project

add .htaccess file to

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|robots|favicon.ico|\.txt|\.html)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /Project/index.php?/$1 [L]
```

In your VerificarLogin Controller

```
class VerificarLogin extends CI_Controller {


  public function __construct() {
     parent::__construct ();    
  }

  public function index() {

     if ($this->session->userdata('logged_in')){
        redirect ('/home_usuarios/' ); // where user visit successful login
        exit;
     }
     redirect ( '/VerificarLogin /userlogin' ); 
   }


 function userlogin() {

     $this->load->model ( 'usuarios', '', TRUE );
     $this->load->library ( 'form_validation' );

     //write your code here
 }

}
```

In your view

```
<form method="post" name="users" action="<?php echo base_url ();?>VerificarLogin /userlogin">
```

Comment: add u css folder name in to 
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|robots|favicon.ico|\.txt|\.html)

Answer (score 0):

well actually no problem in your code, but is in SPELLING.

Change Form_validation to form_validation. I hope it is the answer to your question.

Comment: @Ashir I have tested you code, and the whole problem is in your spelling. $this->load->library('form_validation'); and than $this->form_validation->set_rules().....

Comment: @Mohammad... Let's try a different approach: What can cause that my code works in your PC only changing case, but make my code not work in my PC even when I change case???